# Checking client version app on andorid flutter (without Google Play)

Tags: android, flutter

What I have:

- flutter client app for android only,
- myapp.apk file -> users use this file to install application,
- backend in .net,
- JWT.

What I expect:

- when there are changes for client app prompt to user the update is required (force it to the user),
- don't use Google Play.

Is it possible?

What I am thinking:

- versioning API,
- use static client version in backend and every period of time check it is correct
- attach client version in every endpoint
- use someway bitbucket (put latest .apk version)
- use websocket

What is the best way? I want to only implement checking current version, I am not considering update or download latest version right now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by websocket. On server side I've created `WebSocketController` with required client version. On client side I've used [web_socket_client](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_client) and created something like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final appVersion = await getVersion();
  final backoff = LinearBackoff(
    initial: const Duration(seconds: 0),
    increment: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    maximum: const Duration(seconds: 3),
  );
  final socket = WebSocket(
    Uri.parse('ws://api_address/ws'),
    backoff: backoff,
  );

  socket.connection.listen((event) {
    if (event is Connected || event is Reconnecting || event is Reconnected) {
      runApp(
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: socket.messages,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != appVersion) {
              return RequiredVersionAlert(
                  appVersion: appVersion, requiredVersion: snapshot.data);
            }
            return const App();
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  });
}

Future<String> getVersion() async {
  PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  return packageInfo.version;
}
```

I've used `web_socket_client` because there is reconnecting mechanism. There are two streams one for connection with server status and second streams for receiving messages (for my case message is a required client version).